# Will firebase authentication reset password work by changing domains?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using flutter and firebase to create an app and want to implement a reset password feature. To do this I have been trying to use the Firebase Authentication sendPasswordResetEmail function, and have learned that these emails are not being sent to microsoft outlook emails(due to an error on their end, see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/firebase-authentication-emails-are-blocked-by-office-365/m-p/3750188). So, my question is will changing the domain of my firebase auth to a different one fix the problem? And if so, is there a free way to do that?